# webform to pdf drupal5

Tags: drupal, pdf

greeting,

I've create a contact site using webform (fields: name, email, message). That part is easy. Now my next phase is to fetch the data into a pdf and send it to the user. Basically what I want is when the user click the submit button, his/her email address will automatically receive an email from the site attach a pdf file containing the data/s filled in the form.

PS: I'm using drupal v5.2.

Hope anyone can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Drupal is very badly out of date, which I'm sure you know. My experience with creating PDFs in the past was to look into PECL libraries. For example: http://pecl.php.net/package/pdflib

The person who manages this modules is very responsive and helpful...
http://drupal.org/project/fillpdf

Answer (score 0):

A fine example of using Webform to do this is [here](http://bigsnowball.com/content/output-drupal-webform-pdf).